# Not able to solve a run time exception in my project

Tags: android, runtime

[image: this is the error]

I am developing a small project where i got a error which am unable to solve showing force close the application. Can any one help me

and this is my screen3 code

```
public class screen3 extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    String[] names = new String[] { "India", "Malaysia"};
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.screen3);
        // Create an array of Strings, that will be put to our ListActivity

        // Use your own layout and point the adapter to the UI elements which
        // contains the label
        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.screen3,
                R.id.label, names));
        Button b4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.click);
        b4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i2 =new Intent(screen3.this,screen4.class);
                startActivity(i2);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        // Get the item that was clicked
        Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        String keyword = o.toString();
        if(keyword.equals("India"))
        {
            Intent i=new Intent(screen3.this,new21.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
        Toast.makeText(this, "You selected: " + keyword, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

    }

}
```

and 
the 26 line code is

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i2 =new Intent(screen3.this,screen4.class);
                startActivity(i2);
```

and i checked that it is fine

Comment: show us code in `option.matrix.screen3.onCreate()` (file screen3.java), specially around line no.26

Comment: wow you really think we are magicians? How do you expect us to help you if you only provide the logcat screenshot. Copy/Paste some of the code that is bothering you, maybe we'll be able to help you.

Comment: sorry, i have edited it and pasted all the code of screen3. Thanks for the response

Comment: Thanks..... i got caught the error

Answer (score 0):

You have a null pointer exception on line 26 in your Screen3 onCreate method...